# iText not converting unordered lists (from HTML to PDF)

Tags: html, pdf-generation, itext

I am using iText to convert plain HTML to PDF. The problem is iText does not seem to convert my `ul` and `li` tags.

My JSP is:

```
<ul class="list-unstyed list-inline">
   <c:forEach var="a" items="${qvm.esito.attachments}"
              varStatus="attachmentstatus">
       <li class="text-center">
           <a href='/intranet/utils/download/folder/${a.filename}'><theme:displayDocumentThumbImage
                    filename="${a.filename}"/></a>

            <p>${a.fileTitle}</p>
       </li>
   </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

and my function is:

```
String path = Configuration.getTomcatTempFolderPath() + File.separator + "report.pdf";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));
document.open();
```

XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(html));
    document.close();

...

I don't see how my code is important because I manage to download a pdf file but the information in the ul and li tags is not displayed and the pdf generated stops at the first encounter of the ul tag.

Comment: Please show us your code and your html. It's hard to give an answer without it.

Comment: Your "html" is not HTML, more likely something like a JSP Java Server Page.

Comment: Is this iTextSharp or iText (.Net or Java)? `ByteArrayInputStream` and the casing on `getInstance` leads me to think iText (Java).

Comment: *yes its .jsp* - then process the JSP to generate HTML and feed the HTML into the `XMLWorker`.